# Ubuntu local IP address does not resolve

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, hugo, networkmanager

I set a Hugo web server, which listen on localhost:30000.
The ubuntu machine has the 192.168.2.137 address.

When i do:

```
curl http://localhost:30000/ -> OK
curl http://127.0.0.1:30000/ -> OK
```

but,

```
curl http://192.168.2.137:30000/ -> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.131 port 30000: Connection refused
```

What could be the reason for that?

My /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml looks like:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
ethernets:
  enp0s3:
    dhcp4: false
    addresses: [192.168.2.137/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.2.1
    nameservers:
      addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
  lo:
    renderer: networkd
    match:
      name: lo
    addresses:
      - 192.168.2.137/24
```

I also add an entry to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.2.137 localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that it’s listen on localhost so if you use other interface  it won’t work which is normal . You should listen on all interfaces or listen to  the interface enp0s3.